# google custom search limit no of results

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-custom-search

i want to get on top 40 result from google api when i am limiting the result using the below given code it not working ,so how can i get top 40 result by the google api

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var cx = '006925870720824680899:dalusahelrm';
        var gcse = document.createElement('script');
        gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
        gcse.async = true;
        gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx+"&start=1&num=40';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
    })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the "webSearchResultSetSize" attribute to your Search Element.  It will let you have up to 20 results per page.
See https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#supported_attributes

Something like this:

```
<script>
(function() {
    var cx = '006925870720824680899:dalusahelrm';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
</script>
<gcse:search webSearchResultSetSize=20></gcse:search>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list), it's not possible to return more than 10 results in a single request.

> Valid values are integers between 1 and 10, inclusive.

[This Google support document](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/1361951?hl=en) suggests that you perform additional queries, and increment your start value if you want to fetch more than 10 results.

> Google Custom Search and Google Site Search return up to 10 results per query. If you want to display more than 10 results to the user, you can issue multiple requests (using the start=0, start=11 ... parameters) and display the results on a single page. In this case, Google will consider each request as a separate query, and if you are using Google Site Search, each query will count towards your limit.

Comment: can you suggest me gcse.src for my required results

Comment: It's not possible to do in a single request. You will need to write a function to make multiple requests e.g. with start=0&num=10, another with start=11&num=10 etc.

Comment: can you write me gcse.src for 10 results